# How to hide default navigation bar button and add custom button in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

I have one navigation based application in which i want to hide the default navigation 
which is display at left side and i want to add my own custom button.I have written following 2 code.

code sample 1:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    appDelegate=[(FoodAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Volunteers_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 86, 30)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

But this displays default navigation button.

second code sample:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DontWorryAboutThis" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
    [barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Volunteers_back.png"]];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

This one displays both button default and custom overlapping each other.
Does anyone have any idea what is the problem here?or any sample code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to hide the back button.  If you replace the leftBarButtonItem, it should overwrite whatever button is there.  I use this code, and ONLY this code to accomplish this in several of my apps.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cancel"
                                 style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target: self
                                action: @selector(actionButtonCancel)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnCancel;
[btnCancel release];
```